# Unconditional authentication

Tags: authentication, perfect-secrecy, universal-hash

I have a few questions regarding [universal-hash](/questions/tagged/universal-hash) functions:

1. Is there a way universal hash functions can be used to provide unconditional authentication in the way the OTP provides unconditional security?
2. Assuming a TRNG is used how could this be combined to form a perfect cryptosystem, assuming PSK's  are secured?
3. Is there unconditional non-repudiation(acceptance by third-party) to go along with this?
4. And lastly, why are these hash functions not used as a SHA-#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $\;\;\;$ Sure. $\:$ The simplest way is to OTP-encrypt the

   $\;\;\;$ output of an almost [xor-universal hash family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-independent_hashing#Mathematical_Definitions).
2. $\;\;\;$ That could be used for [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/24353/991), where

   $\;\;\;$ the MAC is applied to an ordered pair that indicates

   $\;\;\;$ [the message number or how far into the pad to start] and the OTP ciphertext.

   $\;\;\;$ (Presumably, the pairing function would be $\;\;\; \langle x,\hspace{-0.03 in}y\hspace{-0.03 in}\rangle \: \mapsto \; $[prefixfree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code)$(x)\hspace{.04 in}||\hspace{.04 in}y \:\:\:\:$.)
3. $\;\;\;$ [Yes.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unconditionally+secure+signatures)
4. $\;\;\;$ The tightest way I'm aware of to get provable universality while still hopefully being

   $\;\;\;$ [second-preimage resistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack) is the trivial construction that just concatenates an output

   $\;\;\;$ from a universal hash family with the output from a standard cryptographic hash function.

Comment: So a universal hash function is not cryptographically secure (pre/second/collision resistant). Is it actually multiple hash functions together so  could not become a SHA? In addition after looking this up I found a paper that said to MAC-THEN-ENCRYPT would provide unconditional security. http://www.researchgate.net/publication/271371156_On_security_of_universal_hash_function_based_multiple_authentication , is your suggestion better? In addition why strongly universal is there not an actually universal family?

Comment: Yes. $\:$ My suggestion (now removed) was worse. $\:$ All strongly universal hash families $\hspace{1.27 in}$ are universal hash families. $\;\;\;\;$